# Qt Quick: QML/C++ expression cannot be used as function?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, integration

could you take a look and explain, what am I doing wrong in code below?

```
#ifndef BACKEND_H
#define BACKEND_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtQml>

class BackEnd : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int player READ player WRITE player_change)
    QML_ELEMENT

    int player;                         
public:
    explicit BackEnd(QObject *parent = nullptr);

signals:
    int player_changed(int player);

public slots:
    int player_change(int player);

};

#endif // BACKEND_H
```

cpp:

```
#include "backend.h"

BackEnd::BackEnd(QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent}
{

}

int BackEnd::player_change(int player)
{
    return (player == 1) ? 2 : 1;
}
```

Error:

```
Expression cannot be used as a function
```

Error appears in auto-edited moc file...

Removing Q_PROPERTY makes it fine...

Comment: READ requires a function, e.g. `READ read_function`. Your mistake is you supplied a member variable. A quick fix would be `READ get_player` with `int read_player() const { return player; }`. The other issue is for good property binding, you should implement NOTIFY to let QML know when your property had a new value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says that the `Q_PROPERTY` macro can't use the member `player` as a function.

> A READ accessor function is required if no MEMBER variable was
> specified. It is for reading the property value. Ideally, a const
> function is used for this purpose, and it must return either the
> property's type or a const reference to that type. e.g.,
> QWidget::focus is a read-only property with READ function,
> QWidget::hasFocus().

You need to create a getter and use it as the `READ` function. Or you use `MEMBER`.

> A MEMBER variable association is required if no READ accessor function
> is specified. This makes the given member variable readable and
> writable without the need of creating READ and WRITE accessor
> functions. It's still possible to use READ or WRITE accessor functions
> in addition to MEMBER variable association (but not both), if you need
> to control the variable access.

Have a look [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/properties.html#requirements-for-declaring-properties).

```
#ifndef BACKEND_H
#define BACKEND_H

#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>
#include <QtQml>

class BackEnd : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int foo READ foo WRITE setFoo NOTIFY fooChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(int bar MEMBER bar NOTIFY barChanged)
    QML_ELEMENT

public:
    explicit BackEnd(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject{parent} {}

    int foo() const { return m_foo; }
    void setFoo(int val) { m_foo = val; emit fooChanged(); }   

signals:
    void fooChanged();
    void barChanged();

private:
    int m_foo;
    int bar;
};

#endif // BACKEND_H
```

Comment: note that when not using `MEMBER`, you need to emit the `NOTIFY` signal yourself.
`setFoo` should `emit fooChanged();`.

Comment: I like how in your answer you show both `READ` and `MEMBER` correct implementations for a Q_PROPERTY. Both of them demonstrate good practice and both of them could be considered solutions to the OP's question. Also, bonus for adding `NOTIFY` which wasn't asked in the question, but, is also good practice.